# What're the rank of these "kernel" matrices used often in machine learning?

Tags: probability, matrices, probability-theory, measure-theory, machine-learning

Let $\{x_1, \dots x_n\} \in \mathbb{R}^{p\times 1}$ be $n$ **distinct** columns vectors. Consider the $n \times n$ "kernel" matrix used often in machine learning community:

$$K:= [k(x_i,x_j)]_{n \times n}$$

where:

$$k(x_i,x_j):= f(\frac{||x_i-x_j||^2}{p})$$

where $f: [0, \infty)\to [0, \infty)$ be a sufficiently smooth function.

(1) What can we say about $rank(K)$ when $f:= Id$?

(2) What can we say about $rank(K)$ when $f:= 1$ on [0, 1) and $0$ otherwise?

(3) What can we say about $rank(K)$ when $f(r):= e^{-r/2}$? (This is the case of "*Gaussian kernel*").

Comment: Won't this depend on the choice of the $x_{i}$ as well as on the function $f$? For example, in your question (2), the rank of $K$ will be 1 if the distances between the $x_{i}$ are all very small. And the rank will be $0$ if the $x_{i}$ are all sufficiently far apart. And you can probably get anything in between with other choices.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Thanks for your comment! Yes you're right in saying that for (2), the matrix depends on the individual choices for $x_i,x_j$ in this case. Here, after a reararrgement of indices of $x_i'$s, $K$ will be a block diagonal matrix where the non-zero block will be square blocks of $1$'s. But I can't see why it'd eventually alter the ranks of $K$ too much: $K$ seems to be low rank in this case, because of the blocks consist of $1$'s. 

In general, I don't think that for (1) and (3), the rank of $K$ will vary a lot if we vary the distance between the individual points $x_i, x_j$.

Comment: For (2), you can get everything from a matrix of all 1s (or even all 0s) to an identity matrix, so the rank can be anything from 0 to n. That's about as variable as possible. The blocks consisting of 1s has no effect on the rank (other than the size of the blocks affecting the rank, but they can have any possible size).